# CSS not working on every element

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

Here's my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .leftRightBorder select, 
    .leftRightBorder textarea, 
    .leftRightBorder input[type=text] 
    {
        width: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Here's the top portion of my page as an image:
[image]

The CSS styles/spaces/lengths (is that a word) everything on the page beautifually, but this top section is still weird, the maturity date two dropdowns, and value date is a little weird too. Here is the ASP for this top section:

```
<tr id="tr14">
    <td id="td15">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaturityDate) %>
    </td>
    <td id="td16" style="width: 150px;">
        <%= Html.TextBox("MaturityDate", Model.MaturityDate.HasValue ? 
              Model.MaturityDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "", 
              new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "MaturityDate", 
              onchange = "parseAndSetDt(this); ", dataType = "Date" })%>
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => 
              m.AmortizationComponent.MaturityBusinessDayConvention,
              DropDownData.BusinessDayConventionList(), "", 
              new { propertyName = 
                  "AmortizationComponent.MaturityBusinessDayConvention", 
              onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
    </td>
    <td id="td17" style="width: 76px">
        Value Date
    </td>
    <td id="td18" style="width: 150px">
        <%= Html.TextBoxWithPermission("RateTimeStamp", 
              Model.RateTimeStamp.HasValue ? 
              Model.RateTimeStamp.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "", 
              new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced }, 
              new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "RateTimeStamp", 
              onchange = "parseAndSetDt(this);", dataType = "Date" })%>
        <br />
        <%= Html.CheckBoxForWithPermission(m => m.Current, 
              new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced }, 
              new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "Current", 
              onchange = "UseCurrent();UpdateField(this);" })%>
        Current
    </td>
</tr>
```

Why isn't this part being styled effectively?

Comment: show your final markup, as seen by the browser. Not server side tags, ideally provide an example of the problem on http://jsfiddle.net. Nobody is supposed to know what your custom HTML helpers such as `TextBoxWithPermission` generate as markup. Then you can safely remove the `asp.net-mvc-2` tag as that's clearly a CSS issue.

Comment: can you provide the actual HTML output rather then ASP code? will help to help you.

Comment: any parent of the tr has the class leftRightBorder?

Comment: "a little weird" isn't descriptive enough. Can you provide some arrows or something in your image that gives an idea of where you expect your elements to be?

Comment: Where is the class for .leftRightBorder defined in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS doesn't work on every input element the same way in every browser.  In IE, most of the inputs are still drawn by Windows Forms so they are not quite CSS compliment.  But in Chrome and Firefox everything works for the most part, but you may have to tweak the margins and size specifically for the `select` element.

And if you want to support the Mac, you really need to forget about the sizing, because the Apple OS decides to do it's own thing regardless of settings, sort of the same problem I mentioned above with IE.

Don't become overly anal about this, because at this point in history you can't control every aspect of the input in the same way, and you are going to drive you self crazy if you try to.  Things are getting better with the browsers specifically IE 9, but don't hold your breath that they will work how you want.

*Note* I also have assumed it is in oversight, but `leftRightBorder` doesn't show up anywhere in the code you posted.  I am making the assumption the problem you are posting about isn't as simple as forgetting the class.